# how to implement search functionality in popup modal in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

**Here is my problem,**
I want to create a pop up modal which contain text input field and button and drop down list to select which column. And when I search , it should show the result in a table or grid  in the same modal with links to select each record.

I'm new to the asp.net mvc and I don't have much background. I only want to know that how should I do this? what should I use(eg. jsonResult, ajax etc.) to implement this? Can someone explain me the steps? I  know it's lot to ask. Can someone please help me?
I've created a partial view with html beginform to pass the string Query form view to controller and here it is,

```
    @model SmartPhotographer.Models.Client
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
      <title>Index</title>
   </head>
   <body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Reservation", FormMethod.Post))
     {
       <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <th colspan="2" align="center">Person Details</th>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>Search text: </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
            </td>
            <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
          </tr>
       </table>
     }    
    </body>
   </html>
```

and my action result for that partial view,

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Search(Client ClientDtl)
    {
        string FirstName = ClientDtl.FirstName;
        Session["search"] = FirstName;
        return PartialView();
    }
```

and I've passed the session variable to another action to find the record,

```
    public ActionResult Search()
     {
        string SearchText = Session["search"].ToString();
        var Search = from m in db.Client
                     select m;
        Search = Search.Where(s => s.FirstName.Contains(SearchText));
        return PartialView("Search",Search);
    }
```

and i want this searched results to show in same partial view.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: i'm sorry for my incomplete question. Thank your for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Ajax Toolkit that will let you create a modal popup. You can then implement your desired functionality in the modal.

The modal will be just like a panel, you can place the controls you want inside the modal and preform your search etc.